# shell command to parse xml is not behaving properly

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to parse below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tzn="http://tzn.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/TznTtApp" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
  <acs orgn="*" sbdomains="true"/>
  <tzn:application id="ca9i.TznTtApp" package="ca9i" required_version="1.0"/>
  <apptype>14</apptype>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <feature name="http://tzn.org/fate/sn.se.al"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <name>TznTtApp</name>
</widget>
```

so i am using below shell script

```
echo -e 'cat //*[local-name()="apptype"]/text()' | xmllint --shell  /data/2211334455/894949890051_1.0.4/config.xml | grep -v "^/ >"
```

But i am getting the output like

```
-------
14
```

And expected output is

```
14
```

so can anyone tell me what mistake am i doing ?

Comment: Wow, you're actually using the right tool for the job, as opposed to the vast majority of similar questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is just part of the output when you use the `--shell` option. One alternative would be to just use `--xpath`:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="apptype"]/text()' config.xml
14
```

The `--shell` option launches an interactive shell, which you're currently passing commands to using `echo`. `--xpath` is used to return the results that match an XPath. It looks like this is exactly what you want in this case.

If there's a good reason that you're using `--shell`, I guess you could add to your grep filter:

```
$ echo 'cat //*[local-name()="apptype"]/text()' | xmllint.exe --shell config.xml | grep -v '^\(/ >\| -\)'
14
```

This filters out any lines starting with `/ >` (as in your attempt) or `-`, so the other undesired line is removed too.

Comment: can you please explain difference between xpath and shell. whats grep command doing here.

Answer (score 1):

xmllint has an option `--xpath` to evaluate xpath expression.

For your example, you can just do:

```
 xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="apptype"]/text()' your.xml
```

to get only `14`